# jQuery push text to array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, push

I'm simply just trying to push the text of an `li` element when I click the add button. But when I click my add button, it is pushing all the items in my list to the array. I guess it's because I'm just using a class. What would be the best way around this? Thanks in advance!

**HTML**

```
<div id="products">
    <ul>
        <li><p>Lorem 1</p><button class="target">Add</button></li>
        <li><p>Lorem 2</p><button class="target">Add</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var array = Array();
    $(".target").click(function() {
        $('p').each(function (i, e) {
              array.push($(e).text());  
        });
        console.log(array);
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('p')` selects all p elements. You want to select only the one that came before the clicked element. `.prev`

Comment: Do you want to be able to add it more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var array = [];

    $(".target").click(function() {
        array.push($(this).siblings('p').text()); //Replace with this and it will get the text from clicked li only.
        console.log(array);
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think it will, `$(this)` will be the button, not the `li`.

Comment: the button doesn't have any child p elements.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var array = []; //Use the bracket notation instead.

    $(".target").click(function(e) {
        var p = $(this).closest('li').find('p');
        array.push(p.text());

        console.log(array);
    });
});
```

Basically you want to find the closest `li` enclosing your `.target` (the one which was clicked) and then find the paragraph contained in that `li`.

Comment: Thanks @kgr , that's exactly what I've been looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: `.prev()` may be more appropriate than closest/find here.

Comment: @Mark is right, `prev` or `siblings` might be better (simpler) but I meant to show the idea of using `this` and traversing DOM from that.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code essentially says:

When an element of the class "target" is clicked, push **EACH** of the paragraph elements text to the array.

Consider replacing this:

```
$('p').each(function (i, e) {
    array.push($(e).text());    
});
```

with:

```
array.push($(this).previousSibling.text());
```

This will instead add the text value only from the paragraph element which immediately preceded the button that the user clicked.