# Get button text in to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got multiple buttons. These buttons are created dynamically. Each button has a unique button text.

How can I get the button text in to an array?

```
<button type="button" class "utClass">uniqueText1</button>
<button type="button" class "utClass">uniqueText2</button>
<button type="button" class "utClass">uniqueText3</button>

var butTxArr = [];
$("#intoArr").click(function(){
    //how to get the button text into butTxArr
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery push text to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618846/jquery-push-text-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` function along with `.get()`:

```
$('.utClass').map(function(){
  return $(this).text();
}).get();//returns ['uniqueText1','uniqueText2','uniqueText3']
```

Comment: Can I do `butTxArr.push($(this).text();)` to get all into `butTxArr` array?

Comment: you can concat returned above array to get them in butTxArr .

Answer (score 1):

Try This  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxntq4fg/):

```
var butTxArr = [];
$("#intoArr").click(function(){
    $('.utClass').each(function(){
       var obj = $(this).text();   // get the text of button
       butTxArr.push(obj);         //Add it to an array  
    })
});
```